# How to share vector icon while being able to change Fill brush

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

In .Net 4.6, I use shared vector icons implemented as Path in Canvas in a global xaml like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Canvas x:Key="mSearchCanvas" x:Shared="False" Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Data="M9.5,3A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 16,9.5..." Fill="Black" />
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary
```

I can then  reuse these icons in several applications using:

```
<Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" Child="{StaticResource mPencilCanvas}"/>
```

It works well but I'd like to use the same icon/Canvas with different Fill brushes.

Is there a simple way to override Fill property with new value?

Comment: You should only use the geometries as resources, i.e. the value of the Data property.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, this was an options but I've kept a surrounding Canvas to specify its Width and Height because they are related to coordinates used in Data. Moreover I don't see how it permits me to more easily set Fill.

Comment: Instead of a ViewBox you would use a Path, set its Data property to the icon resource and its Fill to whatever brush you want. The Stretch property would control how the icon geometry is stretched. Using a UIElement (like a Canvas) as resource is a bad idea anyway, because you cannot use it multiple times unless you set `x:Shared`.

Comment: @Clemens I try to follow your proposal. In my global ResourceDictionary, I've moved icon drawing to a PathGeometry whose content is Data's M syntax string. I can reuse it into a Canvas settings its Path property to my geometry static resource and separatly set its Fill property. But what WIdth and Height must I used to this Canvas?

Comment: Which Canvas? You don't need one. Set the Width and Height of the Path.